# Would it be possible to use the DS1302 made for Arduino?

Tags: gpio, hardware, rtc

I got some spare [DS1302](http://www.cytron.com.my/viewProduct.php?pcode=BB-RTC-1302&name=Real%20Time%20Clock%20Module%20c/w%20Battery) chips that I'd like to connect to my Raspberry Pi to use as a RTC, but I'm not so sure how to. How would I go about it?

Comment: So, you have answered your own question right? If so, you should put this as an answer, not inside of a question. Right now it's unclear if you have any unanswered  question.

Comment: hey there @KrzysztofAdamski, i can't because i just made this account. something about having to wait 8 hours

Comment: OK, just be sure to move it to the answer when you can. You can even self accept it. This will help others having the same issue. Also note that DS1302 is supported by Linux kernel driver and this is another option to use it. I may add another answer describing how to do this when I have some time or you may explore this yourself.

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski, sure thing.

Comment: You can also use the DS1307. It's easy to interface because you can just use I2C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the guide from [hobbytronics](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-real-time-clock) as a reference, with this [module](http://www.cytron.com.my/viewProduct.php?pcode=BB-RTC-1302&name=Real%20Time%20Clock%20Module%20c/w%20Battery) i got from Cytron

#### 1. Connect it to the RPi's GPIO

```
RST  (CE)  -> GPIO#17
I/O  (DAT) -> GPIO#18
SCLK (CLK) -> GPIO#21 
GND        -> GND 
VCC        -> 3v
```

#### 2. compile source

http://pastebin.com/gF09XSFn

```
cc rtc-pi.c
```

this is for the rev 1 board, mine was the rev 2 so i had to update the definitions in the source:

http://pastebin.com/YJ22Sayh

```
#define SCLK_OUTPUT *(gpio+GPIO_SEL2) &= 0xFF1FFFFFL; *(gpio+GPIO_SEL2) |=0x00200000L
#define SCLK_HIGH *(gpio+GPIO_SET) = 0x08000000L
#define SCLK_LOW *(gpio+GPIO_CLR) = 0x08000000L
```

#### 3. execute the compilation

output from the compilation would be a a.out file, rename it to rtc-pi and set the date with something like this

```
sudo ./rtc-pi 20131216175500
```

or to set it from the current time

```
sudo ./rtc-pi `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
```

this will set the time. now all you need to do is to invoke it during every startup to keep the date

```
sudo ./rtc-pi
```

#### Misc

to quote the guide from hobbytronics

> I also found that a pullup resistor is needed between DAT and VCC (=
>   3.3V). A 10k..30k resistor seems to work fine.

Now i didn't do this at the moment because i don't have any resistors with me, not so sure about the impact of it.

Comment: a resistor between DAT and VCC makes sure your I2C setup conforms to the standard -- DAT should be HIGH when there's no data transfer going on.

Comment: I also had to change `GPIO_ADD` form `0x20200000L` to `0x3F200000L` as indicated [here](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-real-time-clock).